# Java 8 test list sort Comparator and thenComparing

Tags: java, junit, java-8, comparator

How can i test a list sort with Comparator and thenComparing

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(ObjectA::getA()) //some int
    .reversed()
    .thenComparing(a -> a.getY().isX()) // some boolean             
    .thenComparing(ObjectA::getB())) // some String
```

How can i test this sort in junit. I try something:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1).forEach(i -> {
    assertTrue(list.get(i).getA() >= list.get(i + 1).getA());
    asssertTrue(Boolean.compare(list.get(i).getY().isX(), list.get(i+1).getY().isX()) > 0);
    assertTrue(list.get(i).getB().compareTo(list.get(i + 1).getB()) < 0);
});
```

Only the first assertion works, the rest fails.

Comment: Why are you testing code you didn't write?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertions are wrong. the second `Comparator` is only applied if the first `Comparator` returns 0, and the third `Comparator` is only applied if the first and second `Comparator`s return 0.

Therefore `Boolean.compare(list.get(i).getY().isX(), list.get(i+1).getY().isX())` should be <= 0 only if `list.get(i).getA() == list.get(i + 1).getA()`.

And `list.get(i).getB().compareTo(list.get(i + 1).getB())` should be <= 0 only if `list.get(i).getA() == list.get(i + 1).getA()` and `Boolean.compare(list.get(i).getY().isX(), list.get(i+1).getY().isX()) == 0`.

Comment: I know. How can i write a test to check the comparator. That is the question.

Comment: @emoleumassi what aspect of your code example do you want to test?

Comment: @Holger. The sort of the list. Is the list sorted with the criteria?

Comment: @emoleumassi that’s not how *unit testing* is supposed to be done. Do you want to test a) the implementation of `sort` (usually not, as not implemented by yourself) or b) the implementation of the comparator factory methods (also normally not done by you, as you’re not the implementor) or c) the functions you’re passing to the comparator factory methods (usually not needed for such trivial functions, but if you’re not trusting them, write dedicated tests for these methods, instead of testing the result of a complex sort operation).